# What is the term for a group of liches?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, collective-nouns

What is the term for a group of *liches*?

> In fantasy fiction, a **lich** (/ˈlɪtʃ/; cognate to Dutch *lijk*, German *Leiche*, Norse *lík* and Swedish *lik* all meaning "corpse") is a type of undead creature. [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lich)

A group of unicorns is a *blessing*.  So what is a group of *liches*?

Comment: African or European liches?

Comment: @DVK - Laden or unladen?

Comment: The plural if _lich_ is _lichen_.

Comment: @JohnLawler - I which case a *moss of lichen* might fit.

Comment: (Frankly, it's whatever the fantasy community decides it is.  Not clear why the question would have been migrated here.)

Comment: Are we talking about *leeches* -- little bloodsucking worms?

Comment: (Or, to mix the etymology, a *lick* of lichen might work.)

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill - Let's keep politics out of this!

Comment: Honestly, I don't think this is one of those words for which a mass of such entities (and a word to designate such) would exist. Mythologically speaking, they were reputed to be very rare, territorial, and prone to engage in the most heinous of magic. I suspect, while relatively powerful, they might be a bit insecure and untrusting since all of their work, for which they died to be come undead, could be undone if you could find their phylactery. Hence I can't see too many liches having relationships where more than one of them would be seen at a time, let alone working together enough to name.

Comment: @Thaddeus: Mythologically speaking? I haven't researched it too deeply, but my impression is that the specific concept of "liches" used in D&D and the like was essentially a composite of multiple actual myths and legendary creatures, codified by fantasy writers; the idea of a species or general category of "liches" is not an actual myth of real people. So I don't know what myths you could be alluding to.

Comment: You can always invent your own. It's not like "a blessing of unicorns" is some ancient phrase; somebody just thought it sounded right and used it, and it got popular. Most of these obscure terms for groups of things are just jokes anyway.

Comment: I vote for the term "a liching". It has panache.

Comment: Sounds like the OP has 99 problems, but a lich ain't one.

Comment: I played a LOT of D&D around the time that "Trading Places" came out.  In one campaign, our party surprised a necromancer in his lair, and our DM sang out - in a spot-on Eddie Murphy impression - "Where my liches at?"  It still makes me laugh when I think of it, and the word "lich" has cracked me up ever since.

Comment: I'd recommend "a dammit of liches", because that'd be a tame version of most heroes' reaction to seeing a group of liches.

Comment: I was hoping that Wondermark's list of supernatural collective nouns would've had liches, but no dice. It does have plenty of others, though, like "a basement of vampires": http://wondermark.com/566/

Comment: I came across this post while trying to think of a group name for my own RPG. For fantastical creatures it is fitting to invent a proper term. I took inspiration from a funeral procession "Pall-bearers" and the "Pall" which is the death shroud. I decided to give it a twist and think of them, instead of as death mourning, as more Death-Bringing.. So for my small group of "Sithlords" in my Star Wars RPG I will refer to them as a "Pall" of Sithlords.

Answer (score 3):

*[Terms of venery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun#Terms_of_venery_.28words_for_groups_of_animals.29)* are a linguistic amusement from the Late Middle Ages.

The *[Book of St. Albans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Saint_Albans)*, printed 1486, offered names for 165 different animal groups, including a *gaggle* of women, and a *diligence* of messengers, and influenced the Standard English Lexicon through Gervase Markham's *The Gentleman's Academic* in 1595.

Modern *[group names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_names)* often reflect an essential quality of the creatures, for example:

> - a *flight* of butterflies
> - an *intrusion* of cockroaches
> - a *bask* of crocodiles
> - a *gaggle* of geese
> - a *pride* of lions
> - a *sneak* of weasels
>
> *Wikipedia.org*

Naming groups of animals is fun, and naming sci-fi creatures should be just as fun:

What if a *blessing* of unicorns ran into a:

- ***curse*** of liches
- ***graveyard*** of liches
- ***[Hydra](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hydra?q=Hydra#Hydra)*** of liches
- ***morgue*** of liches
- ***stench*** of liches

Use your goriest imagination of a *[lych](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lich&allowed_in_frame=0)*.

Comment: You could have included _apocalypse_. No wait, that's for zombies.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an established collective noun for this fictional creature. Unicorns have somewhat an established collective noun because unicorn is a well-known legendary/fictional animal. *Blessing* can fall under *terms of venery* and these terms are more prevalent when we are more familiar with the animal and if they are used more frequently in literature.

Having said that, one can use their imagination to coin a collective noun for *liches* and it would be more suitable if fiction writers do it. You can also use different collective nouns depending on the context.

For example, One of the writers used ***scores***:

> The demon waddled into the main hall on its short legs. There were **scores of liches**.
>
> *Lord of the Isles, Volume 1* By David Drake

And one used ***chorus***:

> "The Weave... collapsing," answered the **chorus of liches**.
>
> *The Ghost King: Transitions, Book 3* By R.A. Salvatore

But in the end, you can always use ***group*** itself [like some writers do](https://www.google.ca/search?q=prevalent&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=TE81VeHaO9W1yAT3z4DIDA#q=%22group%20of%20liches%22&safe=off&tbm=bks).

---

I could also find some collective nouns used in fantasy role-playing game related texts.

From [Tibia Wiki](http://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Updates/10.1):

> Woe and behold! **A plague of Liches** threatens Drefia's Deeper Vampire Crypts.

From [Baldur's Gate Wiki](http://baldursgate.wikia.com/wiki/History_of_the_Dead_Three):

> Through armies of skeletons, legions of zombies, hordes of noncorporeal undead, and **a gauntlet of liches** they battled.

I could also find [a gaming forum discussion](http://archive.4plebs.org/tg/thread/36034050) where people are trying to find collective nouns for legendary/fantastic creatures and there are two suggestions for *liches*:

- **a pall of liches**
- **a lynch of liches**

Comment: I think "score" here is used in its literal sense, meaning "twenty" in the same way one might say, "dozens of soldiers."  It's not a collective noun. Similarly, the "chorus" is probably imagery meant to describe how they are acting together, like an "army of street sweepers," not a collective  noun. A pod of whales, a parliament of owls, or a murder of crows doesn't function like a pod of peas, the Parliament of England, or the murder of Jesse James.

Comment: "Scores" means large numbers here.

Comment: @ermanen yes, multiples of twenty.

Answer (score 1):

Liches, by the nature of the person who usually succeed in becoming them, tend to be smart, cunning, ambitious and treacherous. 
So, the only time I could see a group of them working together it would really be a sort of "shake your hand while trying to stab you in the back" proposition for all involved. So, a cabal maybe?

Alternatively, since there is no specific term for a group of them that I know of, you could just use the term for a group of undead creatures, since they fit that decision, and there are a lot of different ones. The most fitting of those that I can think of would be a "scourge".

Comment: Thanks ermanen. I would have done that myself, but I wrote this on a mobile device in a hurry